# Arranging letters in words

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> your letters are A, A, E, N, S, T, T, T. Find the probability that AAE is together in any order

We consider $AAE$ as one so $AAE \to O$

We have $O, N, S, T, T, T$, ways to arrange this is $6!/(3!) = 6*5*4 = 120$. Ways to arrange $O$ itself are $3$ so total our favored event is $120*3 = 360$.

Total possible: $8!/(2!3!) = 8*7*6*5*2 = 3360$

Thus $P = 360/3360$

Is this correct?

Comment: For the sake of computing probability, you can (and should IMO) count identical arrangements as unique. Thus, the probability is $\frac{3!\cdot(5+1)!}{(3+5)!}$.

Comment: This answer is the same as yours, but I'm not so sure that your method would work for any other combination of letters.

Comment: Yes you are correct (in this case). One follow-up question: what if you now have $3$ A's and $2$ O's? Then your method might not work immediately. In that case, how should one do it?

Comment: @k99731 I don't understand your question but if you have a question then post it as new question.

Comment: @miracle173 Forget about it then. Your approach is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your answer is correct.

Taking the alphabets that comes together as a group is nice approach.

But if you write the ways of arranging O iteslf as $\frac{3!}{2!}$ It looks more understandable.